# PHP bit/value conversions are not working as expected

Tags: php, oop, int, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

### UPDATE:

For the googlers, here is the corrected version:

[pastebin.com/tPVWM4MF](http://pastebin.com/tPVWM4MF)

---

I am trying to create a class that can interpret integer values the same way some default php functions do (e.g. `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);`). For some reason, a few of my outputs have unexpected outcomes (see the code).

See this page for more info on: [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

How can I fix these unexpected outcomes?

The Code:

```
<?php

class bitwise {
    private $xchng = array(
        'bit' => array(
            0000,  0001,
            0010,  0011,
            0100,  0101,
            0110,  0111,
            1000,  1001,
            1010,  1011,
            1100,  1101,
            1110,  1111
        ),
        'val' => array(
            0000 =>  0,  0001 =>  1,
            0010 =>  2,  0011 =>  3,
            0100 =>  4,  0101 =>  5,
            0110 =>  6,  0111 =>  7,
            1000 =>  8,  1001 =>  9,
            1010 => 10,  1011 => 11,
            1100 => 12,  1101 => 13,
            1110 => 14,  1111 => 15
        )
    );
    
    public function create_bit_str($int_input){
        $xchng = $this->xchng['bit'];
        // convert value to bits
        $vals = str_split((string) $int_input,2);
        $values = '';
        foreach ($vals as $val) {
            $val = (int) $val;
            if(isset($xchng[$val])){
                $values .= $xchng[$val];
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return (int) $values;
    }
    
    public function create_val_str($int_input){
        $xchng = $this->xchng['val'];
        // convert bits to value
    }
}


$bit = new bitwise;
var_dump($bit->create_bit_str(12 & 10)); // output 1000 (expected)
var_dump($bit->create_bit_str(12 | 10)); // output 1110 (expected)
var_dump($bit->create_bit_str(12 ^ 10)); // output 72 (unexpected) should be 0110 or 110
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump the contents of your 'bit' array. You're not getting the values you think you are. Put them in quotes and you'll get the expected results.

Edit: do the same in your vals array. You're specifying decimal numbers. In other words, 0010 means **ten**, not **two**.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I had actually done that in the original version of the script on another computer, and I guess I forgot to add it back in.